# get pathanme in universal router

Tags: reactjs, history, server-side-rendering, react-starter-kit

In [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) there's [withRouter HOC](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) that provides access to `location.pathname`

How can I get it in Universal Router?

`history.location.pathname` is only available in the browser so can't use that.

Comment: You can use something like `var pathname = require('location').pathname();` that is set by server.

Comment: what's `location`? I'm getting `Module not found: Can't resolve 'location'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have universal routes like this:

> ```
> const routes = {
>   path: '/page',    
>   name: 'page',            
>   parent: null,             
>   children: [],             
>   action(context, params) {
>     return '<h1>The Page</h1>'
>   },
> }
> ```

(example from documentation https://github.com/kriasoft/universal-router/blob/master/docs/api.md). then you will have `context.pathname` inside the action. Hope it will help!